# Ng-Repeat works only one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple template like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in edit_elements">
    <label>{{e.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="e.model"/>
</div>
```

And object for ng-repeat:

```
[{'label': 'test-label-1' , 'model': 'test-1'}, 
 {'label': 'test-label-2' , 'model': 'test-2'}]
```

`ng-repeat` works when page rendering, but only once, next time i see only labels content, inputs are empty. How to debug `ng-repeat`? I put console.log before rendering and object is filled correctly, but inputs are empty.

Thank you.

Comment: I added Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/604/ so try to play there or edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic debug just use `<pre>{{edit_elements|json}}</pre>`

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="InitCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="e in edit_elements">
        <label>{{e.label}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="e.model" />
    </div>

    <pre>{{edit_elements|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/604/)</kbd>